# Font cambria of website is not working on any android devices

Tags: android, html, css, angularjs

I have implemented a website using AngularJs. I used several fonts including cambria and calibri using font-family, The fonts are working perfect on Webiste and even on Ios Mobiles (Safari browser) however the same is not working on any Android device i have checked for all android versions and browsers

i have used

```
font-family : cambria
```

in css.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanking you.

Comment: Are you using web fonts? If not ,Android doesn´t have Cambria installed by default.

Comment: There are only three standard fonts on adroid: normal (Droid Sans), serif (Droid Serif) and monospace (Droid Sans Mono). So it is normal that your font won't work.

Comment: yes we are using web fonts, but we are really not sure what can be done to solve this issue

Comment: Show your web font code

Comment: body {
    font-family: cambria;
    background-color: #2f4050;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #676a6c;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}

Comment: Your code is not for web fonts, but for system fonts... read carefully the solution bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android devices generally don't have the font Cambria installed on their systems, so the Android browsers can't display text with this font.

You can use a CSS font stack so that if one font is not installed the browser will try to use the next one:

```
font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
```

---

Or you can look at [Web Fonts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).

On your website, put the font Cambria at a url like `/cambria.ttf`. Then you can use it in CSS like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyCambria';
  src: url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

Now use

```
font-family: Cambria, 'MyCambria', serif;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much .Worked for me