# Do I need to use a ttf upload for cross-browser font support?

Tags: html, css, linux, fonts

I have read that some web platforms like Android have very limited font selections and that supposedly "web-safe" fonts actually don't work.

For example, [some websites describe a long list of "web-safe" fonts](https://kinsta.com/blog/web-safe-fonts/) like Cambria, Rockwell, Palatino, etc.

However, when I render pages that specify these fonts using Chrome on an Arch Linux computer, none of these fonts work. For example, code like:

```
h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Cambria;
}
```

will turn the text white, but the font will just be a default font, not Cambria. None of the other "web-safe" fonts work either. So, does web-safe just mean web-safe for people running Windows? If that is the case, do I basically have to do a ttf upload to support such fonts on Android, Linux, etc?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read.

Comment: Use something like `font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067693/font-cambria-of-website-is-not-working-on-any-android-devices ; This tells the renderer to use Cambria if available, if not use Georgia (more widely available) and if that isn't, use any serif font.

Comment: I.e. the font-family is a list with decreasing specificity.

Comment: Just use a font content-delivery site, for instance one of the google ones (other brands are available) and you're good to go.